# Why does my POST to Sagepay returns an Error 400?

Tags: java, post, server, opayo

I am trying to integrate my application with Sagepay, using the Server Integration Protocol. I have written my code in JAVA and currently I am at the point where I'm sending a POST to Sagepay to be redirected to their payment page. However, I get a blank screen which is a result of an Error 400 (Bad Request).

In their documentation, they specifically state that:

> The data should be sent as URL Encoded Name=Value pairs separated with & characters and sent to the Sage Pay Server URL with a Service name set to the message
>   type in question.

The URL that I have constructed is this:
https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/vspserver-register.vsp&VPSProtocol=3.00&TxType=PAYMENT&Vendor=foovendor&VendorTxCode=foovendor-1459865650735-78597&Amount=10&Currency=GBP&Description=This+is+the+description&NotificationURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&BillingSurname=foosurname&BillingFirstnames=fooname&BillingAddress1=fooaddress&BillingCity=foocity&BillingPostCode=foopc&BillingCountry=UK&DeliverySurname=fooname&DeliveryFirstnames=foosurname&DeliveryAddress1=fooaddr&DeliveryCity=foocity&DeliveryPostCode=foopc&DeliveryCountry=UK&CustomerEMail=foo%40foo.com

What am I missing?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: echoing @jr593 .  URL params imply a GET rather then a POST.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url doesn't setup the query string properly.
Ithink that

```
register.vsp&VPSProtocol
```

should be

```
register.vsp?VPSProtocol
```

I.E. Question mark instead of ampersand.

Also, you said a post was required, but pasting that url in a browser will send a GET request, won't it ?

Comment: Note that a question with a typo shouldn't be answered, instead you can comment for the OP. It should then be closed. There is a specific close reason with the text *This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.*